# Manipulating Joomla Content

Tags: php, html, css, joomla, content-management-system

I have a Joomla! site and I am trying to create my own modules. What im struggling with is how to get the information from joomla like article title, article content, article image etc.

Specifically I'm trying to edit the Category Blog display built into joomla. The template I have does not stylize the category blog so I need to do this myself. I want to add the title of each blog item, a short description, and the image. I then need to stylize the content with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redefine the view of a component exists for a particular template, you must create the same view in the file structure of the template. For example, to change the view of an article simple:

```
/templates/yourtemplate/html/com_content/article/default.php
```

More info on http://docs.joomla.org and http://jeffchannell.com/Joomla/custom-component-views-in-joomla-15.html

Also, you need to read the documentation for Joomla! on how to create your own modules.

- Creating a simple module - http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_simple_module

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

In relation to the modules you can read the title, html content, images (i.e. parse image links from within the content field) from your Joomla's ###_content table.

For the second item - You can use overrides to modify the blog category in your template. i.e. in your template folder you create html/com_content/category/ and copy the files you want modify from the appropriate location (components/com_content/category/). These will then override the Joomla core component. You can make the css changes in your normal template styles file.

More on template overrides here: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

here's another link for J1.5. Pretty much the same principal.
http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides